# Git subtree not properly using .gitignore when doing a partial clone

Tags: git, version-control, split, gitignore, subtree

I am a graduate student with many scripts, bibliography data in bibtex, thesis draft in latex, presentations in open office, posters in scribus, and figures and result data.  I would like to put everything in one project under version control.  Then when I need to work on a portion such as the bibliography data, I would like to check that subdirectory out, modify it as necessary and merge it back.I would like the ability to check out one version to my home computer, and a different one to my work computer and make changes to each independently and eventually merge them back.  I would also like to be able to check out a piece of code from this big project and import it with versioning into a separate project.  If I may changes I'd like to be able to merge them back to the original project.

Based on my understanding git subtree can do this.

http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree

There is an example that is along the lines of what I'm trying to do at:

http://psionides.jogger.pl/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/

Say the trunk of my project contained the directories: (bib  bin  cfg  data  fig src  todo).

When I use

```
git subtree split -P bib -b export
git checkout export
```

I get a the bib directory, plus **all files that should have been ignored** or considered binary based on .gitignore such as the src directory and everything in it that ends in a tilde or the ./data directory.

```
dwickrama@DWwork:~/research/trunk$ ls * -r
biblography.bib  JabRef

src:
script1.sh~ README~         script2.sh~
script3.sh~ script4.R~  script5.awk~
script5.py~ 

cfg:
cfgFile1.ini~  cfgFile2.ini~  cfgFile3.ini~

bin:
bigBinaryPackage1   bigBinaryPackage2

dwickrama@DWwork:~/research/trunk$
```

My .gitignore file is as follows:

```
*.doc diff=word
*.tex diff=tex
*.bib diff=bibtex
*.py diff=python
*.eps binary
*.jpg binary
*.png binary
./bin/* binary
*~
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Have you looked into using submodules? They're designed for this sort of thing, and a bit more automated...

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Subtree supposedly has many advantages outlined at:
http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200904#30

Comment: @D W: That's fair - submodules are far from perfect. Just wanted to make sure it was out there as an option.

Comment: I don't see the first example on the site you linked (maybe it's in the git-subtree docs). The second, though, is similar to one on the tutorial blog post - except you've left off the -b option, which creates a branch for the subtree. Is that what you meant to do? (I think yours is probably just printing the SHA1 of the subtree)

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes the first site is the git-subtree docs where you can download git-subtree.  I linked there because supposedly there are two projects called git-subtree.

Are you recomending:

    git subtree split -P bib -b export

giving as output:

    Created branch 'export'
    884842f6f4e9896e2e4e9402ee0ef762cd617257

I'm pretty new to version control in general, so this question will probably sound silly.  Where is the exported directory?

Comment: @D W: I think you really need to read and understand the walkthrough on that blog. I'm just retyping things that are already written there. For this particular step, you're not actually creating a new directory. You're creating a branch within the same repository which represents only that subtree. From there, you can make another repo containing only that branch - that's the very next step in the tutorial.

Comment: @Jefromi: Ah yes I can see that now.  http://git-scm.org/course/svn.html also explains that well.  Thank you for the help, I will spend some time going through this.  I will post the full solution here if I get it for people equally confused as me.

Comment: @D W: Excellent. Feel free to post more specific questions (separate from this one, if appropriate) if they come up - the whole subtree thing is doing some interesting things with repositories, and they're much easier to understand if you have a good idea of how git works inside.

Comment: @Jefromi: I tried it out and I get something really weird as updated in my original question.  Everthing that was supposed to be ignored in the parent (main repository directory and subdirecties) that should have been ignored is included.

Comment: @D W: Ignored files are of course not removed when you check out a different branch. And on the other branch, they're not ignored, because the .gitignore is not part of that subtree! If you create a separate repo and fetch from this branch (as shown in the tutorial) those files won't be brought over - they're not tracked, they're just remaining around through the checkout.

Comment: @D W: This whole Q&A in the comments thing isn't really the way SO is intended to work. I guess at some point I'll write up some instructions so there can be a real answer for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like all those ignored files aren't actually in your repo - they're just leftover from your previous checkout.

Since you extracted a particular subtree from your original project, your .gitignore file is no longer present, so the files are no longer being "ignored", so you'll see them in git status.  But they also aren't part of your repo; they're just sitting there.

Try using 'git clean' to clean them up.

Comment: What about environment stuffs such as node_modules or vendor?

Answer (score 4):

I think this isn't anything really specific to git-subtree, you'd have the same situation if you switched between two branches and one of them generated some extra files that were in gitignore and the other wouldn't know about them... I'd say this behavior of git is rather correct, because if I add a file to gitignore, I expect it will completely ignore it and won't do anything with it - that includes also not deleting it when you move to a branch where it's not gitignored...

The possible ways you can deal with this would be:

- add the same files also to the gitignore in subdirectory/subproject
- do git clean before you switch branches
- just ignore this, after all, you probably won't do much work in the branch that was generated by git subtree split other than pushing the commits outside... if you do want to work on the subproject separately, then maybe just checkout the subproject itself in another directory outside the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.gitignore` file is incorrectly mixing [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) syntax with [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) syntax.

The `.gitignore` file should only have patterns. Stuff like

```
*.py diff=python
*.eps binary
```

belongs in the `.gitattributes` file instead.