# Make branches of git-subtrees that don't contain gitignore files

Tags: git, gitignore, git-subtree

I recently started using git-subtree to keep a few github sub-projects inside a parent repository that syncs to a private server. I'm having trouble managing .gitignore files in my subproject branches.

I need to be able to make branches of the sub-projects, which will then be pushed to github, and to be able to pull down branches of the sub-projects from github as well. I've tried this both by using the "git subtree split -b" command and by making branches directly from the github repo and then pulling them down into my parent repository.

However, I've been having trouble with the files listed in .gitignore because I don't want them to be inside these branches. I saw this Stack Overflow post ([Git subtree not properly using .gitignore when doing a partial clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503816/git-subtree-not-properly-using-gitignore-when-doing-a-partial-clone)), which describes a similar situation, but I can't just use git clean as suggested because I don't want to delete the files entirely, just to make sure they are not committed or pushed to github. I also don't want to put gitignore files in each of the subtrees, because I don't want the public github repos to contain the names of my private files.

Is there a way to make branches that won't include the ignored files?